# Is it possible to fill entities on JHipster from an HTTP?

Tags: java, json, post, httprequest, jhipster

I just started working with JHipster and I created a .jh file with the entities I want. I would like to fill all the entities by doing an HTTP request to an existing HTTP:PORT that already has my needed information.

I would like to know if it's possible? I'm currently trying with this method that I found online:

```
private static void sendPOST() throws IOException {

    // URL obj = new URL(POST_URL);

    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("admin", "admin".toCharArray());
        }
    });

    String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/table-simple-tasks";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) URL.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    // For POST only - START
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    // For POST only - END

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("POST request not worked");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what uses the client code (Angular or React) generated by JHipster, you can also see it in action in API docs menu 
 which uses swagger-ui. So yes you can do it from some java code but you should consider using a higher level abstraction than HttpURLConnection, maybe something like Spring RestTemplate. although I'm nt sure what your question is, if you have some code just test it,

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had help where we used mapping to get the info from the json file.